# Thread safety for arrays in D?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, d

Please bear with me on this as I'm new to this.

I have an array and two threads.

First thread appends new elements to the array when required

```
myArray ~= newArray;
```

Second thread removes elements from the array when required:

```
extractedArray = myArray[0..10];
myArray = myArray[10..myArray.length()];
```

Is this thread safe?
What happens when the two threads interact on the array at the exact same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not thread safe

this has the classic lost update race:

appending means examening the array to see if it can expand in-place, if not it needs to make a (O(n) time) copy while the copy is busy the other thread can slice of a piece and when the copy is done that piece will return

you should look into using a linked list implementation which are easier to make thread safe

Java's `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` uses the list [described here](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/u/michael/PODC96.html) for it's implementation and you can implement it with the [`core.atomic.cas()`](http://dlang.org/phobos/core_atomic.html) in the standard library

Answer (score 4):

No, it is *not* thread-safe. If you share data across threads, then you need to deal with making it thread-safe yourself via facilities such as [synchronized statements](http://dlang.org/statement.html#SynchronizedStatement), [synchronized functions](http://dlang.org/class.html#synchronized-functions), [`core.atomic`](http://dlang.org/phobos/core_atomic.html), and [mutexes](http://dlang.org/phobos/core_sync_mutex.html).

However, the other major thing that needs to be pointed out is that all data in D is thread-local by default. So, you *can't* access data across threads unless it's explicitly [shared](http://dlang.org/migrate-to-shared.html). So, you don't normally have to worry about thread safety at all. It's only when you explicitly share data that it's an issue.

Answer (score 2):

It is not thread-safe. The simplest way to fix this is to surround array operations with the `synchronized` block. More about it here: http://dlang.org/statement.html#SynchronizedStatement

Comment: Note that multiple `synchronized` blocks (without an expression) do not synchronize between each other.